# ЧПУ и дублирование страниц

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, чпу

Есть страница вида http://site.ru/category/file.php
Необходимо сделать http://site.ru/file/

В .htaccess прописал

```
RewriteRule ^file/$ /category/file.php [QSA,L]
```

Ссылку прописал http://site.ru/file/
Все работает, но теперь ссылки доступны по двум адресам http://site.ru/category/file.php и http://site.ru/file/
Что можно прописать, чтобы при запросе http://site.ru/category/file.php был редирект на http://site.ru/file/ ?